# How to simultaneously run the same Python script with thousands of different input files in Microsoft Azure Data Factory

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, batch-processing, azure-batch

I have a Python script that reads in data from a .txt file, processes it and then outputs a .txt file. The difficulty is that I have thousands of .txt input files that I need to run through the Python script, so I have turned to Microsoft Azure to run them simultaneously in the cloud.

I'm very new to Azure and cloud computing, but so far I have managed to run a Python script through the Azure Data Factory. It uses a custom Batch Service to run "python main.py", which outputs data to an output blob container in my Azure Storage account.

How do I change this to iterate over all the input .txt files that I have stored in an input blob container?

Thanks

Comment: You could use the ForEach activity inside a Data Factory pipeline, and enable the parallelism, but even that wouldn't run thousands in parallel, the max batchCount is 50. Refer ADF [parallel execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#parallel-execution).

Comment: Another alternative is to write python based Azure function app that has HTTP trigger, that takes the file from your blob container and outputs .txt file to the blob container. Then invoke your http function from another python program[use pool multiprocessing module], that also would parallelize proportionate to the max number of cores in that system, will not be 1000 in parallel.

Comment: If my answer was helpful , You can Accept it as an Answer, so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the name of your files through a LookUp activity to a ForEach containing your python script?

Answer (score 0):

As the question is regarding Azure Data Factory, ForEach Activity is the best option. But as suggested by @[Anand Sowmithiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14973743/anand-sowmithiran) in comment section, ForEach Activity has limitation of batch count of 50.

1 is the minimum value for the batch count. This will convert the foreach activity from parallel to sequential.

5 is the default value for batch count of foreach activity.
The maximum value for ADF foreach batch count is 50.

**Workaround** –

Design a two-level pipeline where the outer pipeline with the ForEach activity iterates over an inner pipeline.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity#limitations-and-workarounds